# Cleaning a genes database polluted by non-numeric characters except plus and minus signs

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have this genes database which is completely messed up by extra non-alphanumeric values. This happened as a sort of encryption to the data which was made incorrectly, and I don't know how to clean it up. I tried `sed` and `awk`, but failed. This is sample of the data which is a very large amount of documents:

```
chr2#@!!~/\/=\^%$74711&&*&127472363@Pos1%%0^^+
chr3#@!!~/\/=\^%$74723&&*&127473530@Pos2%%0^^+
chr1#@!!~/\/=\^%$73530&&*&127474697@Pos3%%0^^+
chr2#@!!~/\/=\^%$17469&&*&127475864@Pos4%%0^^+
chr3#@!!~/\/=\^%$12747&&*&127477031@Neg1%%0^^-
chr5#@!!~/\/=\^%$17477&&*&127478198@Neg2%%0^^-
chr7#@!!~/\/=\^%$74781&&*&127479365@Neg3%%0^^-
chr7#@!!~/\/=\^%$74795&&*&127480532@Pos5%%0^^+
chr1#@!!~/\/=\^%$12748&&*&127481699@Neg4%%0^^-
```

The cleaned data must be like this:

```
chr2 74711 127472363 Pos1 0 +
chr3 74723 127473530 Pos2 0 +
chr1 73530 127474697 Pos3 0 +
chr2 17469 127475864 Pos4 0 +
chr3 12747 127477031 Neg1 0 -
chr5 17477 127478198 Neg2 0 -
chr7 74781 127479365 Neg3 0 -
chr7 74795 127480532 Pos5 0 +
chr1 12748 127481699 Neg4 0 -
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try `sed -E 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9+-]+/ /g' file`

Comment: What have your tried? I don't see any code showing effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with `sed`. Something as follows:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9+-]/ /g' file | column -tc2

chr2 74711 127472363 Pos1 0 +
chr3 74723 127473530 Pos2 0 +
chr1 73530 127474697 Pos3 0 +
chr2 17469 127475864 Pos4 0 +
chr3 12747 127477031 Neg1 0 -
chr5 17477 127478198 Neg2 0 -
chr7 74781 127479365 Neg3 0 -
chr7 74795 127480532 Pos5 0 +
chr1 12748 127481699 Neg4 0 -
```

Comment: THIS IS  AMAZING!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you @goro i didn't know how to keep - and +

Comment: Proving answers to users who didn't show any effort to solve the problem isn't encouraged.

Comment: @PedroLobito Says who? This isn't a teaching website, it's a website dedicated to collect answers to problems.

Comment: Says the SO community rules.

Comment: @PedroLobito a link to the rule you mention would be a nice addition to back up the comment

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 7):

With `tr`, transliterating characters from the complement of the wanted set to spaces, and squeezing repeats:

```
$ tr -sc '[:alnum:][:space:]+-' ' ' < data
chr2 74711 127472363 Pos1 0 +
chr3 74723 127473530 Pos2 0 +
chr1 73530 127474697 Pos3 0 +
chr2 17469 127475864 Pos4 0 +
chr3 12747 127477031 Neg1 0 -
chr5 17477 127478198 Neg2 0 -
chr7 74781 127479365 Neg3 0 -
chr7 74795 127480532 Pos5 0 +
chr1 12748 127481699 Neg4 0 -
```

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution

```
awk -F '[^[:alnum:]+-]+' '{$1=$1;print}' file
```